# How to completely remove or reduce top/bottom margins in a table cell in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

See the table below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iZy1.png

There is that extra space between the inner border and the value itself.

My margins are set to 0 but that little space still exists and I am unable to find a way to adjust or remove it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/51OMT.png

Is there an option to remove or reduce that spacing ?

Answer (score 3):

Besides cell margins, paragraph spacing (before, after, line spacing) also influence those.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-spacing-between-paragraphs-ee4c7016-7cb8-405e-90a1-6601e657f3ce

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure paragraph spacing is set to zero "Before" and "After."  Reduce cell margins top and bottom to zero (as you did).  Finally, reduce "Line spacing" to .9 or less to achieve the result you want.[image: Paragraph settings]

Answer (score -1):

According to my testing and research, no matter how we set the top and bottom margins, it will always retain a certain margin.

It seems that these spaces cannot be deleted, and they will definitely keep a certain distance.